# Loading images from folder take to much time

Tags: android, performance, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a lot of pictures on a path , and i move picture to this path , loading pictures and displaying them on recyclerView  take a lot of time , and i am using a fragment , when i change fragment and back to the one that display pictures , it take again a lot of time to load pictures .

any suggestion to load pictures fast ?

````
  suspend fun getImages() = try {
        val path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .toString() + "Here folder path "
        val directory = File(path)

       

        val files = directory.listFiles()
        if (files.isEmpty()) {
          //
        } else {


        }
        for (i in files.indices) {
            println( files[i].name)


            val myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(files[i].getAbsolutePath())
            var path = files[i].getAbsolutePath()
            var fileName = files[i].name
            var picture = Picture(myBitmap, path, fileName)
            if (picture != null) {
                listPictures.add(picture)
            }
        }
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
            myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

        }

    } catch (e: Exception) {
      

    }
```
````

Comment: Use an image-loading library, such as Coil, Glide, or Picasso. Do not load the images yourself, one at a time, on the main application thread.

Comment: They should be lazy loading in each `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` off of the main thread.  Taking into account that this would require viewholder lifecycle/scope management, which can be non-trivial, as per the suggestion above - use a library for problems like this that have already been solved.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that using a library is the official recommendation too - see here: https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap Those libraries can do things like caching as well, so not only is the app's performance better while images are loading, they can display a lot faster (e.g. in a list you're scrolling up and down) when you've already loaded them before